# Elasticsearch 2.x, search not returning highlight array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a really tough time spotting what's wrong with this query. I do get results for the query, but highlights are not included.

`{
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "foo", 
                "default_operator":"AND"
            }

        },
        "highlight":{
            "fields": {
                "title":{}
            } 
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing elasticsearch is matching _all for querystring query and hence is not highlighting. Try

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "title:foo", 
            "default_operator":"AND"
        }

    },
    "highlight":{
        "fields": {
            "title":{}
        } 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify default_field like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "foo",
            "default_field": "title", 
            "default_operator":"AND"
        }

    },
    "highlight":{
        "fields": {
            "title":{}
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. And what if I want to match against all fields but only want to highlight the match if it happens to be in title?